# How to do unicode(hexadecimal) in Facebook to output a character?

Tags: facebook

How do I write unicode, in hexadecimal, to Facebook "What's on your mind" box?

I have tried writing:

```
\u00B9
"\u00B9"
&#xb9
"&#xb9"
```

none worked so far

(let me add that I am doing this from a MAC)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Alt+0185 on the keyboard if you are using Windows, it should have the desired output for you.

Comment: does this work on Facebook for Windows?  I know in Microsoft Office it will.

Comment: I don't have a Windows computer, so I'm not sure. It should work. Test it. If it works, check this as the answer. If not, comment so everyone can benefit from the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that facebook converts it all to human-readable string. I think that isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

The examples in the lead are HTML entities. They would need to be ended with a semicolon, but no matter, they do not work in a Facebook comment. The answer supplied was not, the original poster said that he was using a Mac, not Windows, so the ALT- method does not apply. I know that I did once enter Greek characters, as I was talking about stars in constellations with Greek designations like α Vir, but I don't recall how to do that now and the UNICODE universe may have been usurped by Facebook's stupid emoticon universe.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, if you do not wish to use the Character Viewer, you can set your preferences to allow input of Unicode characters by code like in Windows.

[How to use the Character Viewer](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/keyboards/charpalosx.html)

[Entering Unicode characters by code](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1899290?tstart=0)